# AcroField changes made using itext7 in C# do not commit/are not visable due to hybrid AcroForm-XFA issues

Tags: c#, adobe, itext7, xfa, acrofields

Project is to fill existing forms programmatically from a database/datagridview and allow the user to edit the forms afterwards as the database does not hold all values needed.

I am able to get the values, and put them into the form however:

1. Values set using AcroForms do not show/print when viewing form.
2. Background color change does not show when viewing form.

Both changes appear when clicking into the field.

I understand this is caused by hybrid XFA and AcroForms issues, and that pdfXFA is a paid extension for the itext library. The pdfXFA only works to flatten XFA and I don't need to do that as I need the fields to continue to be editable. I have already tried solutions proposed by the following:

1. [why-dont-the-itext-7-form-field-values-print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41886714/why-dont-the-itext-7-form-field-values-print)
2. [this awesome write up on XFA values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33949461/11210567)
3. [This tutorial including .RemoveXfaForm()](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/faq/technical-support/itext-7/how-change-text-color-acroform-field)

Other solutions all reference .RemoveXfaForm() which should remove all the XFA formatting, but doesn't appear to work as intended. Using GetXFA found it remained even after .RemoveXfaForm() was called.

I have tried moving the form.SetNeedAppearances(true) and form.RemoveXfaForm() to before values are set, and after values are set right before the pdf.close() event. I feel like I am just missing something idiotically simple here and could use some help:

```
public virtual void ManipulatePdf(string src, string dst, DataGridViewRow dataRow)
    {
        //Initialize PDF document
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src), new PdfWriter(dst));
        PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdf, true);
        //form.RemoveXfaForm();
        //form.SetNeedAppearances(true);
        IDictionary<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.GetFormFields();
        PdfFormField toSet;

        //visits each field, fills dependant on whether dgv column exists
        foreach (string field in fields.Keys){
            switch (dataGridView1.Columns.Contains(field))
            {
                case false:
                    if (field == "Date")
                    {
                        fields.TryGetValue(field, out toSet);
                        //this value is visible
                        toSet.SetValue(dateTime.ToString("D"));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fields.TryGetValue(field, out toSet);
                        //this setting does not commit, issue with hybrid XFA/AcroForm
                        toSet.SetValue("0").SetBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.YELLOW);
                    }
                    break;

                case true:
                    if (dataRow.Cells[field].Value != null && !DBNull.Value.Equals(dataRow.Cells[field].Value))
                    {
                        string value = dataRow.Cells[field].Value.ToString();
                        fields.TryGetValue(field, out toSet);
                        //this value is sometimes visable on finished form
                        toSet.SetValue(value);
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        //form.RemoveXfaForm();
        pdf.Close();
    }
```

I have tried the commented out recommendations in multiple combinations and at this point really just need to find out if I can get this to work or start looking for another solution, (I've already emailed itext, no response) so thank you for any insights!

Comment: Currently trying to see if I can fill using xfa instead, I think this may cause some issues with the field text auto sizing but we shall see!

Comment: That did not work.